# How do I asset an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-testcase

new to postman and JavaScript. I am trying to asset the "message" and ""Some Message." in below postman test script but keep getting an error Please advice where am I going wrong.

```
[
{
    "documentId": "123",
    "documentName": "AB.pdf",
    "status": "Failed",
    "errors": [
        {
            "category": "Invalid",
            "message": "Some Message."
        }
    ]
}
]




**My Script:**
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Error message", () => {
const errormessgae = jsonData.errors.find;
(m => m.message === "Some Message.");
})
```

**Test response** Error I receive is "
Error message | TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure why you are using find method

```
pm.expect(pm.response.json()[0].errors[0].message).to.eq("Some Message")
```

Comment: Honestly I am very new to postman or JavaScript, I saw the same e.g on postman's site. I tried your recommendation but I got this "TypeError: pm.expect(...).to.be is not a function"

Comment: @AaravB sorry updated the answer , postman assertions are chai assertions  so to.be is not chai . corrected it :

https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/